# How to handle null value in entity framework sum function

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

[image: Screenshot]

My code is here:

```
Int64? amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => x.Price);
```

That work fine but through Error database is empty

> The cast to value type **`'System.Int32'`** failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

I want replace it with 0 (zero)
I am using entity frame work with MVC application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
var amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => x.Price ?? 0);
```

EDIT:
If `Price` is not nullable, as mentioned in comments.
so, use this

```
var amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => x.Price);
// for null check for amount use `?? 0`
```

Comment: thanks for Answer but not working Please Give Me another soluation

Comment: @Zubair What the error you are getting? And which database fields are nullable?

Comment: Compilation Error in that code var amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => x.Price ?? 0);  I Also try that code before posting this question please see error Picture in question

Comment: @Zubair What is the datatype of `Price`? Is it nullable and whats about `ItemOrdered`?

Comment: price is int and ItemOrdered id bool

Comment: That is my Item Entity      public bool ItemOrdered { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks a Lot Finaly worked   that code (var amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => x.Price);)

Comment: @Zubair Sum will return null when no record exist, so you can put zero in case of null by using `??` operator.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is NOT that the 'Price' data type is nullable. Actually the problem is that its NOT nullable and there is an empty set. The EF `Sum()` function can only deal with empty sets if its dealing with nullable data. I know this makes no sense since empty sets and nullable types are not the same thing at all. Just cast it to a nullable type and you will get a nullable response. In the empty set case the response will be null. So thats the only case that will work.

```
Int64? amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => (Int64?) x.Price);
```

Comment: LINQ-to-Entities `Sum` will actually return null for an empty set for an SQL query, _despite its declaration of returning a non-nullable value_, because that's what SQL returns. So what the poster originally wanted was:
`Int64 amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => (Int64?) x.Price) ?? 0L;`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone having issues because Price is **not** nullable but the where clause is returning an empty set you can just cast price to be nullable but then move the null coalescing check outside:

`Int64 amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true).Sum(x => (Int64?) x.Price) ?? 0;`

Comment: This is the only answer that actually provides a value when the query returns null.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to filter out null values:

```
var amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered == true && x.Price != null).Sum(x => x.Price);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach by using DefaultIfEmpty method from Linq:

```
var amount = db.Items.Where(x => x.ItemOrdered).Select(x => x.Price).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
```