# EF Core 3.18 get sum and count from related table

Tags: .net-core, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a web api where I am trying to get sum and count of a related table. Using .net core 3 and EF Core 3.1.8.
This is what I have tried:

```cs
_context.Books
    .Include(r => r.BookCategories)
    .Include(r => r.Resources)
    .Include(r => r.Ratings.GroupBy(g => g.Bookid).Select(s => new { SumAllVotes = s.Sum(item => item.Rating) }))
    .ToListAsync();
```

But I just get an error message. (see below).
I find it difficault debugging with EF Core as I dont know where it is going wrong. Have been trying a couple of hours, but whatever I write I get the same error message.
Thought maybe you guys were able to see what was wrong.

**What I want**

I am trying to get Sum of all Rating inside table Ratings.
Rating contains only 0 or 1. And I am trying to sum ratings on each bookid. I wanted to have it in this class `public int SumAllVotes { get; set; }`.
Because I list out all Books...and one of the properties will then be SumAllVotes. (And also CountAllVotes, when I have finished this problem).
By the end I will have a SumAllVotes and CountAllVotes and can calculate the percentage of how many have pressed "1".

Error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is
> not valid.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression
> source, Expression expression, bool thenInclude)

**What I have tried:**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Books>>> GetBooks()
{
    Guid userid = Guid.Parse(this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    return await _context.Books
        .Include(r => r.BookCategories)
        .Include(r => r.Resources)
        .Include(r => r.Ratings.GroupBy(g => g.Bookid).Select(s => new { SumAllVotes = s.Sum(item => item.Rating) }))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Books and Ratings are defined as -

```cs
public partial class Books
{
    public Books()
    {
        Bookmarks = new HashSet<Bookmarks>();
        Comments = new HashSet<Comments>();
        Favourites = new HashSet<Favourites>();
        BookCategories = new HashSet<BookCategories>();
        Resources = new HashSet<Resources>();
        Ratings = new HashSet<Ratings>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte Scaleoffun { get; set; }
    public byte Scaleoflearning { get; set; }
    public int? Goal { get; set; }
    public int? Secondgoal { get; set; }
    public int? Thirdgoal { get; set; }
    public int? Subjectid { get; set; }
    public int? Categoryid { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Estimatedtime { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int? File { get; set; }
    public int? Ownerid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Createdon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lastmodifiedon { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Guid Userid { get; set; }
    public byte? Grade { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public int SumAllVotes { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int CountAllVotes { get; set; }

    public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Curriculum GoalNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual Curriculum SecondgoalNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Subjects Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Curriculum ThirdgoalNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bookmarks> Bookmarks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Favourites> Favourites { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<BookCategories> BookCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resources> Resources { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ratings> Ratings { get; set; }
}

public partial class Ratings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Bookid { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Int16? Rating { get; set; }
    public Guid Userid { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime Createdon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifiedon { get; set; }
    public byte? Active { get; set; }


    public virtual Books Book { get; set; }
    //public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

These are some other solutions I have tried, but got the same error message:

```cs
.Include(r=> r.Ratings.Sum(i=>i.Rating))
```

and

```cs
.Include(r => new { m = r.Ratings.GroupBy(g => g.Bookid) })
```

Comment: Please try to describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I have added more information under **what i want**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to group child entities by parent's Id. When you `Include` one-to-many child entities, they are added to their parent's child list, and hence *grouped by their parent's identity*, based on the relationship between them. All you need to do is tell EF what values you want from that child list.

Change your query to -

```cs
_context.Books
    .Include(r => r.BookCategories)
    .Include(r => r.Resources)
    .Include(r => r.Ratings)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        // set ALL the primitive properties from Books entity
        Id = p.Id,
        Title = p.Title,
        // etc ...

        // set the computed properties
        CountAllVotes = p.Ratings.Count,
        SumAllVotes = p.Ratings.Sum(x => x.Rating)

        // set the related entities
        BookCategories = p.BookCategories,
        Resources = p.Resources     
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

[AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) has a `ProjectTo` method that generates the required query and does the projection (the `Select` part) automatically. You can use that to avoid the hassle of setting all those properties manually.

Comment: Worked as I hoped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use Include with Select. Read [article](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/) how to make queries with Projection (Select). Note, that Rating.Rating is nullable and you need to handle this. Here is a possible code sample:

```
var view = await _context.Books
.Where(your condition)
.Select(item => new
{
     //Todo: fill other props
     SumAllVotes = item.Ratings.Sum(rating => (Int16?) rating.Rating),
     CountAllVotes = item.Ratings.Count,
 })
 .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: `Note, that Rating.Rating is nullable and you need to handle this.` - so what happens if a rating is null?

Comment: Actually, I've just checked, and seems ef core handles it good. So asking for your question - nothing. However, I faced with such problems [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670422/how-to-handle-null-value-in-entity-framework-sum-function), and try to keep attention to such places